# UIBarButtonItems not functioning

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have 4 `ViewControllers`, A, B, C, and D.

- A can segue to B, C, and D.
- B can segue to C and D
- C can segue to D

Shown (crudely) as a graph:

```
A - B - C
 \  |  /
    D
```

A is the root of a `UINavigationController`, as well as the initial `ViewController`. For some strange reason, whenever I segue from B or C to D, the `UIBarButtonItems` of D do not function at all. I add them to the navbar programmatically:

```
    let settingsButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    settingsButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 35, height: 35)
    settingsButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    settingsButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "settings-black.png"), for: .normal)
    settingsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(settingsPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    settingsButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -10, 0, 10)
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        settingsButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
        settingsButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
    }
    navigationItem.setLeftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: settingsButton)
```

In `Main.storyboard` all of the aforementioned `ViewControllers` have a `NavigationItem`. All of the segues between these controllers are Show(push) segues. I notice the `UIBarButtonItem` of D functionality works when I change the segues between B and D as well as C and D to present modally, but this is simply a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

True to the magic of StackOverflow, I discovered the answer in the process of ironing out the question.

The problem was this little rogue line of code:

```
navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
```

In doing work with the navbar in my app I ended up switching from a hidden navbar to a translucent one. Leaving this code here meant the translucent navbar was on top of the `UINavigationBar` created in D (a container `ViewController` with it's own programmatically instantiated `UINavigationController`as a child vc), thus blocking all my user inputs.

Hope this can save someone else some struggle!

Happy coding! :)